# redux-form Validate only the fileds on selected tab content

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is there a way to pass some initialvalue and update them when the tab is clicked and validate only a particular set of fields

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {Field,reduxForm} from 'redux-form'
import { selectreport, decrementStep } from '../../actions.js'

class Step1 extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleChangeTab = this.handleChangeTab.bind(this)
    this.stepBack = this.stepBack.bind(this)
  }
  stepBack (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('reduce step by 1')
    this.props.dispatch(decrementStep(this.props.step))
  }
  handleChangeTab (e) {
    const { title: key } = e.target
    console.log('click values are ', key)
    this.props.dispatch(selectreport(key))
  }

  renderField(field){
    const className = `row form-group ${field.meta.touched && field.meta.error ? 'has-error' : ''}`;
    return(
      <div className=" col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
        <div className={className}>
          <label className="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">{field.label}</label>
          <input 
            type="text"
            placeholder={field.placeholder} 
            className="form-control" 
            {...field.input} />
          <div className="text-danger">
            {field.meta.touched ? field.meta.error : ''}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      );
  }
  onSubmit(values){
    const { step, report } = this.props
  }
  render () {
    const { step, report, parsedAddress,handleSubmit } = this.props
    const { Line1, Line2} = parsedAddress
    let st = JSON.stringify(step)
    return (      
        <form className="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <div className="">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-3">Enter details.</div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="nav nav-pills col-xs-10 col-md-6 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-3 PADD0">
                <div className={report == 'address' ? ('col-xs-6 active') : 'col-xs-6'}>
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#address" title="address" onClick={this.handleChangeTab}>Address</a></div>
                <div className={report == 'phone' ? 'col-xs-6 active' : 'col-xs-6'}>
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#phone" title="phone" onClick={this.handleChangeTab}>Phone</a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="tab-content PADD20PX text-centered col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-md-offset-2 col-md-6 ">
                <div id="address" className={report == 'address' ? 'tab-pane fade in PADD20PX active' : 'tab-pane fade in PADD20PX'}>
                  <Field 
                    label="Address"
                    name="Line1"
                    placeholder="123 Sample Street"
                    component={this.renderField} 
                  />
                  <Field
                    label="address2" 
                    name="Line2"
                    placeholder="APT"
                    component={this.renderField} 
                  />
                </div>
                <div id="phone" className={report == 'phone' ? 'tab-pane fade in PADD20PX active' : 'tab-pane fade in PADD20PX'}>
                  <Field
                    label="PhoneNumber" 
                    name="phone"
                    placeholder="123.456.7890"
                    component={this.renderField} 
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row PADDBOX">
            <div className="col-xs-12">
              <div className="pull-left">
                <div className="pull-left">
                  <button type="button btn-rounded" onClick={this.stepBack} className="btn btn-default">Back</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="pull-right"><button type="submit">Search</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
function validate(values,props){
    console.log("inside validate",props);
    const errors = {};
    if(!values.Line1){
        errors.Line1 = "Enter address";
    }
    if(!values.Line2){
        errors.Line2 = "Enter address";
    }
    if(!values.phone){
        errors.phone = "Enter phone number";
    }

    return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    step: state.step,
    parsedAddress: state.parsedAddress,
    report: state.report
  }
}


export default reduxForm({destroyOnUnmount: false,validate,form:'PostsnewForm'})(
  connect(mapStateToProps)(Step1)
  );
```

Have two tabs one for address and phone.
Trying to submit the form while on address tab, cant submit even if I pass all the validations since the validation on phone tab fails

Is there a way to pass a global state to the validate function and validate particular fields based on an attribute in global state.

Comment: Why do you only want to validate particular fields?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function validate(values) {
  // console.log(values) -> {title: 'asdf', categories: 'asdf', content: 'asdf'}
  const errors = {};

  // validate the inputs from 'values'
  if (!values.title || values.title.length < 3) {
    errors.title = "Enter a title that is at least 3 characters!";;
  }

  // if errors is empty, the form is fine to submit
  // If errors have any properties, redux form assumes form is invalid
  return errors;
}
if (!values.categories) {
    errors.categories = 'Enter some categories';
}
if (!values.content) {
    errors.content = 'Enter some content, please';
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'PostsNewForm'
})(PostsNew);
```

an if statement for the fields you do want to validate.